# Find the lexicographically largest unique string

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I need an algorithm to find the largest unique (no duplicate characters) substring from a string by removing character (no rearranging).

String A is greater than String B if it satisfies these two conditions.

```
1. Has more characters than String B
   Or
2. Is lexicographically greater than String B if equal length
```

For example, if the input string is *dedede*, then the possible unique combinations are *de*, *ed*, *d*, and *e*.
Of these combinations, the largest one is therefore *ed* since it has more characters than *d* and *e* and is lexicographically greater than *de*.

The algorithm must more efficient than generating all possible unique strings and sorting them to find the largest one.

Note: this is not a homework assignment.

Comment: is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: I believe this should be possible in O(n) time, in a single pass.  Space requirements are just an indicator array, one element for each possible character value.

Comment: Are those two rules AND or OR?  That is must both be true or may either one be true, for (A > B)?

Comment: @RBarryYoung if the 2 rules were OR then the answer to 'dedede' would be include 'dedede' or 'edede'.  Both are larger than the other (using OR).

Comment: By your rules, what are the valid substrings for "*dade*"? *d*,*e*, *a*, *de*, *da*, *ade* are clear, **but**, is *dae* one of the valid substrings?

Comment: @emory: NO, those rules specify only precedence, not what's a valid substring.  repeated characters are clearly not allowed.  I am asking  (in my first question) about how *GreaterThan* is determined.  Basically, I want to know if '*de*' is greater than '*dae*'?

Comment: @RBarryYoung You are correct.

Comment: What is the precedence of rules? First one? e.g in bcaaad, d is greater or bca?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Sorry for the confusion, the question has been edited to clear out some confusion.

Comment: @Draco: still need an answer for my "*dade*" question, above.

Comment: @RBarryYoung dae would be valid since it only removed the second d. Since dae is lexicographically greater than ade, the answer should be dae in this case.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  That significantly changes the algorithm.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I think it should be 'd'. Possible substrings in lexicographical order : a, ad, ae, d, da, de, ade, dae, e. 'e' is the biggest. Question doesn't pose any string length constraints besides <= input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me state the rules for ordering in a way that I think is more clear.

String A is greater than string B if

```
- A is longer than B
  OR
- A and B are the same length and A is lexicographically greater than B
```

If my restatement of the rules is correct then I believe I have a solution that runs in O(n^2) time and O(n) space.  My solution is a greedy algorithm based on the observation that there are as many characters in the longest valid subsequence as there are unique characters in the input string.  I wrote this in Go, and hopefully the comments are sufficient enough to describe the algorithm.

```
func findIt(str string) string {
  // exc keeps track of characters that we cannot use because they have
  // already been used in an earlier part of the subsequence
  exc := make(map[byte]bool)

  // ret is where we will store the characters of the final solution as we
  // find them
  var ret []byte

  for len(str) > 0 {
    // inc keeps track of unique characters as we scan from right to left so
    // that we don't take a character until we know that we can still make the
    // longest possible subsequence.
    inc := make(map[byte]bool, len(str))

    fmt.Printf("-%s\n", str)
    // best is the largest character we have found that can also get us the
    // longest possible subsequence.
    var best byte

    // best_pos is the lowest index that we were able to find best at, we
    // always want the lowest index so that we keep as many options open to us
    // later if we take this character.
    best_pos := -1

    // Scan through the input string from right to left
    for i := len(str) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
      // Ignore characters we've already used
      if _, ok := exc[str[i]]; ok { continue }

      if _, ok := inc[str[i]]; !ok {
        // If we haven't seen this character already then it means that we can
        // make a longer subsequence by including it, so it must be our best
        // option so far
        inc[str[i]] = true
        best = str[i]
        best_pos = i
      } else {
        // If we've already seen this character it might still be our best
        // option if it is a lexicographically larger or equal to our current
        // best.  If it is equal we want it because it is at a lower index,
        // which keeps more options open in the future.
        if str[i] >= best {
          best = str[i]
          best_pos = i
        }
      }
    }


    if best_pos == -1 {
      // If we didn't find any valid characters on this pass then we are done
      break
    } else {
      // include our best character in our solution, and exclude it for
      // consideration in any future passes.
      ret = append(ret, best)
      exc[best] = true

      // run the same algorithm again on the substring that is to the right of
      // best_pos
      str = str[best_pos+1:]
    }
  }
  return string(ret)
}
```

I am fairly certain you can do this in O(n) time, but I wasn't sure of my solution so I posted this one instead.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the condition should be AND. The question has been edited.

Comment: Well you can't have more characters and be equal length, so we are both saying the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
string getLargest(string s) 
{
        int largerest_char_pos=0;
        string result="";
        if(s.length() == 1) return s;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();)
        {
            p=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
            {
                if(s[largerest_char_pos]< s[j]) largerest_char_pos =j;
            }
            res+=s[largerest_char_pos];
            i=largerest_char_pos+1;
        }
        return result;      
    }
```

This is code snipet just gives you the lexicigraphically larger string. If you dont want duplicates you can just keep track of already added characters .